# How to use init_if_needed?

Tags: anchor, account, bump

I want to create an instruction where it is **only** possible to initialize a new PDA account if some parameter on another PDA account (same type) is fulfilled. So I was thinking that `init_if_needed` would be the best option for such an use-case.

In the case that the old account does exist, would I still be able to match on the correct bump when using `init_if_needed` - referring to `old_acc`:

```
    #[account(
        init_if_needed
        seeds = [seeds],
        bump = acc.bump,
        payer = payer
        space = SPACE
    )]
    pub old_acc
    
    #[account(
        init
        seeds = [seeds],
        bump,
        payer = payer
        space = SPACE
    )]
    pub new_acc
```

In the normal `init` i would just pass in "bump" without any assignment. Although not sure if I could still check for the correct bump if the account already exists.

**So the question is how to account for the bumb in the case of account existence and non-existence**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just omit the bump assertion (`bump,` instead of `bump = ...,` and let the Anchor generated code manage the calculation of it. There's no way to determine whether the bump assertion should exist based on account existence.